# 'tensorflow' installed but not run in Spider or Jupyter notebook

Tags: tensorflow

I have installed the tensorflow via Anaconda and validated it successfully by below

```py
import tensorflow as tf

hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))
```

It is validated successfully.

But when I open Jupyter notebook or Spider, type:

```py
import tensorflow as ts
```

it appears:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       import tensorflow as ts
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to install Spyder in your Tensorflow environment, along with the libraries (numpy, pandas, matplotlib, etc) via pip.

```
source activate tensorflow
(tensorflow) conda install spyder  
(tensorflow) pip install "libraries"
```

Same with Jupyter.